# Redshift per-user concurrent queries

Tags: sql, concurrency, amazon-redshift

I've got a Redshift WLM queue set to a concurrency of 8 for a single group.  In this group, I've got one user ('looker', my primary BI tool) that runs lots of queries concurrently.

My understanding of this is: up to 8 queries can be run by all members of this group.  But can a single user get to run up to 8 queries concurrently?  Or will the fact that it's a single user act as a bottleneck on the number of queries it can run concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the concurrency that you set (8 in your case) applies to all users/jobs defined for that group.
so if user a has 4 jobs running, user b has 4 jobs running then a request ffreom user c will be queued.

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html

It is not always best to have a lot of jobs running at once on redshift as this can reduce the overall throughput. A single job can often happily take 100% of the resources on its own due to the MPP nature of the system.

A bit of background on MPP.

MPP stands for "Massively Parallel Processing", this technology is the main differentiation for analytics databases like Redshift. The idea behind it, put simply, is that a query can be split up into a number of parallel processes, these processes are independent and share nothing between them. 
See here for a more polished description

https://vldbsolutions.com/technology/amazon-redshift.php

Often, one large query on an MPP database can take up 100% of the resources. This is GOOD thing, however if more queries are submitted concurrently the resource manager will share the resources.
e.g.

1 x big query - 100% of resources - runs in 10 seconds

or

4 x big query - 25% of resources each = all 4 run together in 40 seconds

Comment: awesome thanks!  can you talk a bit more about why MPP means a single job might take up 100% of the resources?